# kitty terminal emulator problems with national characters

Tags: macos, command-line

I am using the [Kitty terminal emulator](https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/) on three different machines, all using the same `.bash_profile` and `kitty.conf`, and all running macOS 11.0.1 Big Sur.

One of the machines (Mac mini M1) does not show special (Danish) national characters such as æøåÆØÅ correctly but shows codes `C&, C8, C%, C^F, C^X, C^E` instead.

When using Vim or SSH into a remote host, the characters show correctly, and when using the build-in Terminal app, they also show correctly.

All the machines use a US English input source, so I type the Danish characters using the option key.

I must be missing some configuration in macOS itself, I think, but I have not been able to find it.